# Can anyone help me clear a whole forest?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to clear a Birch Forest for a future Minecraft Roleplay and `/fill x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2 log 2 replace air` doesn't seem to help. Could it be because I'm playing in 1.12? I think it will take me a while to just fly around using Fire Charges

Comment: What is with people playing in old versions? I've heard it a lot, and it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Big_Chungus 1.12 is much better for servers and has wide plugin/mod support.

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure that the correct syntax that you are looking for is `/fill <x1> <y1> <z1> <x2> <y2> <z2> air replace log`. You put the log before the air but it is really the other way around. So once you've correctly used the command I listed above, you should just have to wait for the leaves to decompose, and you're golden (Just be sure that you list the coordinates correctly.)

Answer (score 3):

From the [command wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#fill):

```
fill <x1> <y1> <z1> <x2> <y2> <z2> <block> <dataValue|state> replace [replaceTileName] [replaceDataValue]
```

You have the fill block and the replace block backwards.  Your command will try to replace all air with birch logs.

This command functions properly:

```
/fill ~-15 ~-10 ~-15 ~15 ~10 ~15 minecraft:air 0 replace minecraft:log 2
```

After which you can also use:

```
/fill ~-15 ~-10 ~-15 ~15 ~10 ~15 minecraft:air 0 replace minecraft:leaves
```

This will replace any type of leaves so be careful if you are trying to save any other type of tree.  If you are clearing any type of tree then you can omit the 2 and the end of the first command to clear any type of log as well.

These commands can be run each time you move around as they will clear a 30 X 20 X 30 area.

---

If you are wanting to just run around to clear trees, you can put use the [execute command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#execute) in a repeating block:

```
execute @p ~ ~ ~ fill ~-5 ~ ~-5 ~5 ~10 ~5 minecraft:air 0 replace minecraft:log 2
```

You can add a chain block to clear the leaves as well.  The coordinates are a bit more conservative to run smoothly.

**Don't forget to turn it off when you are done.**

Comment: I tried, but it always gave me a "Failed to execute 'fill ~-5 ~ ~-5 ~5 minecraft:air 0 replace minecraft:log 2' as Splashy_Puddles" message.

Comment: That message means that it is not currently filling any blocks.  When you clicked the command block there were no logs around to be filled with air.  If you walk to some logs, they should be replaced with air.